# simple update query is slow

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have a MySQL UPDATE query, and I can't figure out, why is it so slow.
The query is `UPDATE profile SET lastfresh=? WHERE uid=?`

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `profile` (
  `uid` mediumint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nick` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastfresh` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `adtk_nck` (`nick`),
  KEY `adtk_wnl` (`nick`,`lastfresh`),
  KEY `adtk_np` (`nick`,`pass`),
  KEY `lng` (`lng`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=182993 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The duration of query's execution is 17 seconds (sometimes). What can be a problem?

Comment: how fast do you want it will be?

Comment: I don't want a specific time, only it seems a little slow for me.

Comment: 17ms is slow for you thats why i am asking that how more fast do you want it will be?

Comment: Sorry It isn't ms, but seconds. I had a mistake.

Comment: How big the table is?

Comment: Rows: 6497, Data: 3.69 MiB, Index: 2.08 MiB, Total: 5.77 MiB

Comment: Your database needs to be tuned properly. Is it busy? Does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show anything insightful?

Comment: tadman, I have now 33 selects/sec, 3 inserts/sec, 5updates/sec and 1delete/sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fine-tune your mysql settings.

One thing that is very important for performance of innodb engine is the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting. Its default value is 8 mb which is very small. Follow the suggestions in this article : http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/

if you want to understand how buffer pool works, this is the link to mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html

Comment: I have the innodb_buffer_pool_size set to 2Gb. Thank you for the urls, I'll check it now and make modifications based on this info.